# Where did Haruka and Sora head in the end in Yosuga no Sora?

Tags: yosuga-no-sora

In Yosuga no Sora, the twin visited another town than Okukozome in the end (in the manga and the game, temporarily, and in the anime, probably for good).  In the manga and the game, the town is said to be in "Northern Europe" and Sora was speaking the Estonian language (according to Google Translate) there.

What I'm concerned about is that in some countries incest is illegal (in Japan, it is not illegal, albeit a cultural taboo).  Assuming they visited a region where it is legal, where might they have headed in the end?

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could create a new tag yosuga-no-sora if you have the sufficient reputation.

Comment: You are asking about laws in another country regarding incest. The scope of your question is off-topic in regards to the site, as defined in the [help center](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you wish to learn more about what countries in Europe have laws prohibiting incest, please locate an [appropriate resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_regarding_incest#Europe) in regards to the subject.

Comment: Your question would be fine if you were just asking about where they eloped to in the end. It is implied to be Estonia, where their mother is said to be from.

Comment: My intention was to ask where they eloped, assuming they went where incest is legal, based on knowledge about laws in Northern Europe countries.

Comment: Then please edit your question to reflect that as your main intent.

Comment: @Krazer Done. By the way, I didn't know that their mother was from Estonia.  Was it mentioned somewhere in the canon?

Comment: In *Haruka no Sora*, it's explained that Sora knows Estonian, which implies that their mother may be from there (since it's mentioned that she's European).

Comment: @Krazer Thank you.  I'd be the most grateful if you could point out where it's mentioned that their mother is European.